# Sending mail in PHP results in undefined index

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get my contact form on my site to operate correctly. I am getting undefined index in regards to the `$name`, `$email`, `$thesubject`, `$message` variables, respectively.

Could anyone tell me what I need to do to get the email to properly send?

**HTML/Form:**

```
            <div class="alert success success-message">
                <div class="close">×</div>
                <p>Your message has been sent!</p>
            </div>

            <form class="clearfix" method="post" action="contact.php">

                <div class="field">
                    <label>Name <span>*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="text" value="" />
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <label>Email <span>*</span></label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="text" value="" />
                </div>

                <div class="field field-last">
                    <label>Subject <span>*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="thesubject" class="text" value="" />
                </div>

                <textarea name="message" class="text"></textarea>

                <button id="send" class="btn">Submit</button>
                <div class="loading"></div>

            </form>

        </div>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

//Retrieve form data. 
//GET - user submitted data using AJAX
//POST - in case user does not support javascript, we'll use POST instead
$name = ($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : $_POST['name'];
$email = ($_GET['email']) ?$_GET['email'] : $_POST['email'];
$thesubject = ($_GET['thesubject']) ?$_GET['thesubject'] : $_POST['thesubject'];
$message = ($_GET['message']) ?$_GET['message'] : $_POST['message'];

//flag to indicate which method it uses. If POST set it to 1
if ($_POST) $post=1;

//Simple server side validation for POST data, of course, you should validate the email
if (!$name) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your name.';
if (!$email) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your email.'; 
if (!$thesubject) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your subject.'; 
if (!$message) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your message.'; 

//if the errors array is empty, send the mail
if (!$errors) {

    // ====== Your mail here  ====== //
    $to = 'myemail@gmail.com';  
    //sender
    $from = $name . ' <' . $email . '>';

    //subject and the html message
    $subject = 'yourwebsite.com / ' . $thesubject . ''; 
    $message = '
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Name:</td><td>' . $name . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email:</td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Message:</td><td>' . nl2br($message) . '</td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>';

    //send the mail
    $result = sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from);

    //if POST was used, display the message straight away
    if ($_POST) {
        if ($result) echo 'Thank you! We have received your message.';
        else echo 'Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later';

    //else if GET was used, return the boolean value so that 
    //ajax script can react accordingly
    //1 means success, 0 means failed
    } else {
        echo $result;   
    }

//if the errors array has values
} else {}


//Simple mail function with HTML header
function sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from) {
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

    $result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    if ($result) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use isset function to check if variable is setup. For example:

```
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : $_GET['name'];
```

Comment: Probably you will have same notice for $errors array, just assign it the empty array like $errors=array();

Comment: Please see my previous comment. And seems you need to use $_REQUEST instead looking to $_GET or $_POST, because in any case $_REQUEST will have $_GET or $_POST values.

Comment: thanks, this worked, just need to get my success message working now

Comment: Maybe you meant "mail" function instead of "sendmail"?